# How to find duplicates inside a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates, 2d

I've tried everything I've found. I actually need to do it calling functions. So far, the only one that produces some kind of results is this code, but the result is wrong. I'd love some help, please.

### Thank you!

```
public class pru {
public static void main (String[] args){
    String ejnombre[][]=new String[][]{
                        {"Lu", "Raul", "Maiz"},
                        {"Dias", "Dick", "Maiz"},
    };

    for (int i=0; i<ejnombre.length; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<ejnombre[i].length; j++){
            for(int k=0; k<ejnombre.length; k++){
                for(int l=0; l<ejnombre[i].length; l++){
                        if (ejnombre[i][j].equals(ejnombre[k][l])){
                            System.out.println(ejnombre[i][j]);

                }
               }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do you only care about detecting them? Or you want their indexes?

Comment: Just iterate over the 2d array, and put the count of every word in a hashmap, then interate over the 2d array again, and check the count of every word you encounter in the hashmap, if the count is greater than 1, you have a duplicate, the running time of the algorithm is O(n*m), where the 2D array is n*m

Comment: I just need to know if there are 2 elements that duplicate. And, to be honest, I'm pretty new to this. The hashmap thing is nonsense to me, I have no idea :c

Comment: It's not nonsense because you don't understand it; that would honestly be nonsense. Use data structures to help you. Nesting a bunch of loops is not only difficult to read and maintain but it's horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also detect all cells that are equal to itself. Simply exclude that case:

```
if (ejnombre[i][j].equals(ejnombre[k][l]) && (i != k || j != l)) {
    System.out.println(ejnombre[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! By the way, do you know how could I use this search and combine it with a search in another array but with different size to find the duplicate between the two arrays? And thank you! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashSet` and iterate your array only one time having your algorithm complexity **O(N)**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ejnombre[][]=new String[][]{
            {"Lu", "Raul", "Maiz"},
            {"Dias", "Dick", "Maiz"},
        };


        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i=0; i<ejnombre.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<ejnombre[i].length; j++){
                if (set.contains(ejnombre[i][j])) {
                    System.out.println(ejnombre[i][j]);
                }
                else {
                    set.add(ejnombre[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Output of this is `Maiz`

Comment: A pseudo code could have been sufficient as this seems like a homework